# Tomcat and open file handlers

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I'm writing a web service using Axis and Apache Tomcat 7.
The service uses a third party library to do some conversions to a file and ends up creating a folder which contains more files (subfolders and regular files). When the conversion is completed the service creates a zip archive and returns it.
When it receives a new request, first of all it removes the files created during the last request and the it starts handling the request.

The service itself works fine, at least the first request is satisfied. 
The problem is that when a second request is received, the service cannot delete all the files generated during the last request.
I'm using Windows XP and with Process Explorer i see that Tomcat is keeping some files (bt not all of them) open and that's why i can't delete it.

Is that possibile that the library i'm using keeps the files open even when the service operation ends?
In the code that i use to create the zip archive it seems that i close all the streams that i open. Btw even if i forgive to close them, can they stay still open after the service operation returns his results to the client?
And if so, why the process Tomcat keeps open only some of the files?

It seems that after some time some file are "released", but other file are always kept open...

I hope someone can give me some advice on how to handle this situation :)

Comment: Do the first and the second requests happen concurrently?

Comment: No, they happen sequentially.
Concurrency isn't took in consideration, for simplicity i'm assuming requests are subsequent one after another.
Since i'm still testing it, it's me who clicks "start" on the client, so concurrent requests cannot happen.

Comment: if a file handler is not released, it will never be released until the servlet container is shutdown. some implementations may also delay the releasing of file handlers to when the object is garbage collected. nothing you can do except to make sure that you close all handlers. if it's the third party libary, then you have to report a bug or fix it yourself.

Comment: You said that it sent a zip stream. did you finish downloading this stream before execute the next request?

Comment: great!
I really hope that the problem is in my procedure to zip the files then :P
The library is opensource but it's not so simple to understand the code.. :/
Btw thank you for your explanation, at least i see things clearly now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I was wondering, the library I'm using doesn't close all the file streams..

I found a workaround that can be used in similar situations. I post it, maybe someone can find it useful or advise me a better way to solve the problem :)

Lucky the jar library can be executed from command line with the java command, so i just executed it with Runtime's exec method in this way:

```
try {   
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar library.jar parameters");
p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this way a new process is created by the JVM, and, when it dies, all the pending handlers are relased.

If you can't execute the library with the java command, such library can be simply wrapped in a custom jar made by a simple class who uses it and takes the needed parameters. The wrapper jar can be then executed with exec().

Comment: You need to drain both stdout and stderr from any external process that you run. Otherwise, you run the risk of hanging the thread that calls Runtime.exec().

Answer (score 1):

Repost of my comment which seems to be useful.

If a file handler is not released, it will never be released until the servlet container is shutdown. Some implementations may also delay the releasing of file handlers to when the object is garbage collected. Nothing you can do except to make sure that you close all handlers. If it's the third party libary, then you have to report a bug or fix it yourself.

My best practice to prevent this sort of problem is to make sure that the file handler is closed in the same method it is opened. If it is not opened in that method, never close it.

```
public void method() {
    //open file handler
    //do something
    //close file handler. make sure it is closed even if there is an exception.
}
```

And never make file handler a field.

```
public class A {
    private FileInputStream fin = null; // never do this. you will have hard time keeping track of when to release it.
}
```

Comment: lucky i tend to not have streams "pending" in a class unless i really have to :)
but thank you again :)